# Render multiple array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am getting two array of objects from APi and trying to render in a table, using spread operator i am combining the two arrays and binding but the problem is  in table it is rendering two times how to combine the two arrays and print as one value in table for one email Id as emailid is unique in both the arrays.

Below is the code and attached link of stackblitz:

```
export default function App() {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
  let data = {
    status: 'success',
    Candidates: [
      {
        Recruiter: 'Pradeep',
        Email: 'Pradeep@gmail.com',
        Total: 11,
        Hired: 2,
        interviewscheduled: 0,
        clientsubmitted: 1,
        Withdrawn: 0,
        Onhold: 5,
        inprocess: 0,
        Rejected: 1,
        Available: 0,
        tobeupdated: 2,
      },
      {
        Recruiter: 'Sudhir',
        Email: 'sudhir@gmail.com',
        Total: 6,
        Hired: 1,
        interviewscheduled: 0,
        clientsubmitted: 1,
        Withdrawn: 0,
        Onhold: 1,
        inprocess: 0,
        Rejected: 0,
        Available: 0,
        tobeupdated: 3,
      },
    ],
    Jobopenings: [
      {
        Recruiter: 'Pradeep',
        Email: 'Pradeep@gmail.com',
        jobopeningTotal: 4,
      },
      {
        Recruiter: 'Sudhir',
        Email: 'sudhir@gmail.com',
        jobopeningTotal: 7,
      },

      {
        Recruiter: 'Marry Scott',
        Email: 'marrys@hsc.com',
        jobopeningTotal: 1,
      },
    ],
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let data1 = [...data.Candidates, ...data.Jobopenings];
    setAllData(data1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table class="table table-bordered rounded">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Recruiter Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Job Openings</th>
            <th scope="col">Hired Candidates</th>
            <th scope="col">Candidates</th>
            <th scope="col">Clients' Submissions</th>
            <th scope="col">Interviews Scheduled</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {allData?.map((eachItem, index) => {
          return (
            <tbody>
              <tr key={eachItem.Email}>
                <td scope="row">{eachItem.Recruiter}</td>
                <td>{eachItem.jobopeningTotal}</td>
                <td>{eachItem.Hired}</td>
                <td>{eachItem.Total}</td>
                <td>{eachItem.clientsubmitted}</td>
                <td>{eachItem.interviewscheduled}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vzlp1c?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Fstyle.css

Comment: that's because your data consists of duplications. Eg, `Pradeep` is present in `Candidates` and in `Jobopenings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary object `obj1` with [Array.prorotype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prorotype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) from the arrays `data.Candidates` and `data.Jobopenings` but keeping track of the repeated data by `Email` and finally get the result array value with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

**Code**:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const obj1 = [...data.Candidates, ...data.Jobopenings]
    .map((o) => ({
      Email: o.Email,
      Recruiter: o.Recruiter,
      jobopeningTotal: o.jobopeningTotal || 0,
      Hired: o.Hired || 0,
      Total: o.Total || 0,
      clientsubmitted: o.clientsubmitted || 0,
      interviewscheduled: o.interviewscheduled || 0,
    }))
    .reduce((a, c) => {
      a[c.Email] = a[c.Email] || {
        Email: c.Email,
        Recruiter: c.Recruiter,
        jobopeningTotal: 0,
        Hired: 0,
        Total: 0,
        clientsubmitted: 0,
        interviewscheduled: 0,
      };
      a[c.Email].jobopeningTotal += c.jobopeningTotal;
      a[c.Email].Hired += c.Hired;
      a[c.Email].clientsubmitted += c.clientsubmitted;
      a[c.Email].interviewscheduled += c.interviewscheduled;
      a[c.Email].Total += c.Total;
      return a;
    }, {});
  const data1 = Object.values(obj1);

  setAllData(data1);
}, []);
```

And here is teh **Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wy9d7t?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You want some way to merge the 2 arrays together such that items with repeated `Keys` (Email in your case) get combined and others get inserted. You can probably find a bunch of libs that already have such helper functions, or you can write a short one yourself.

This should do what you want:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function merge(arrayOne, arrayTwo, key) {
      let result = [...arrayOne];
      arrayTwo.forEach((entryTwo) => {
        let existing = result.find((entry) => entry[key] === entryTwo[key]);
        if (existing) {
          Object.assign(existing, entryTwo);
          return;
        }
        result.push(entryTwo);
      });
      return result;
    }
    setAllData(merge(data.Candidates, data.Jobopenings, 'Email'));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use lodash for it

```
let result = _.unionBy(data.Candidates, data.Jobopenings, "Email")
result =result.map((item,index)=>{ 
return {...item, jobopeningTotal:_.find(data.Jobopenings,{Email:item.Email}).jobopeningTotal }
})

console.log("Your desired output",result);
```

Thank you!